# Without using L'Hospital rule or series expansion find $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x-x\cos x}{x-\sin x}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is it possible to find  $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-x\cos x}{x-\sin x}}$ without using L'Hopital's Rule or Series expansion.

---

I can't find it.If it is dublicated, sorry :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac{x(1-\cos x)}{x-\sin x}=\dfrac{x^3}{x-\sin x}\cdot\dfrac1{1+\cos x}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^2$$

For $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^3}{x-\sin x}$ use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)

Comment: Is  this $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^3}{x-\sin x}$=$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$ i true?

Comment: @1ENİGMA1, What do you think?

Comment: @1ENİGMA1, But one thing is clear: if you know one,, you know the other?

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{x-x\cos x}{x-\sin x}=\frac{\frac{x-x\cos x}{x^3}}{\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}}=\frac{\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}{\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}}$$

then refer to standard limit $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\to \frac12$ and to the link already given for $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$.